# $mysqli variable works on Server but not on localhost

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

On my server I include 'config.php' in each function and it works perfectly, however when I do the same on my LOCALHOST the variable $mysqli cannot be found, will the PHP version differ from server to localhost? The paths are both 100% correct.
The error is as follows;

> Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in
>   C:\Users\PC\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\php\myfunctions.php on line 20

config.php

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'userone', 'password', 'iitb');
```

The connection obviously changes when I use server

myfunctions.php

```
<?php

class News
{
    function getLatest()
    {

        include 'config.php'; // WHERE TO PUT THIS CANNOT FIND MYSQL
        $time = date('Y-m-d G:i:s', strtotime("-1 week"));

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ForumId, ForumTitle, ForumPostText FROM `forum` WHERE `PostDate` > ? ORDER BY PostDate desc LIMIT 5 ");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $time);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($ForumId, $ForumTitle, $ForumPostText);
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows() == 0) {
            echo "<p>No latest article available</p>";
        } else {
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                echo '<p class="posttitle"><a href="post.php?post=' . $ForumId . '">' . $ForumTitle . '</a>    </p>';
                echo '<p class="posttext">' . substr($ForumPostText, 0, 93) . ' ...</p>';
            }
            $stmt->free_result();
        }
    }
    function mostPopular()
    {
        include 'config.php'; // WHERE TO PUT THIS CANNOT FIND MYSQL
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ForumId, ForumTitle, ForumPostText FROM forum ORDER BY Views DESC  LIMIT  5");
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($ForumId, $ForumTitle, $ForumPostText);
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows() == 0) {
            echo "<p>No latest article available</p>";
        } else {
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                echo '<p class="posttitle"><a href="post.php?post=' . $ForumId . '">' . $ForumTitle . '</a>    </p>';
                echo '<p class="posttext">' . substr($ForumPostText, 0, 93) . ' ...</p>';
            }
            $stmt->free_result();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: at your php.ini enable mysqli extension...

Comment: As Svetlio said, you might have the MySQLi extension disabled. Check with phpinfo(); or in the php.ini.

Comment: If MYSQLi is disabled, woundn't it produce a "PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MYSQLi' not found"?

Comment: @MichaelYoo Not if error_reporting is turned off.

Comment: @Svenskunganka If he turned error_reporting off, why would he be getting a `Notice: Undefined variable`?

Comment: It works if i put my $mysqli connection into the function itself but it is abit unprofessional, could put it into a __construct function? PS. PHP.ini is enabled :( and so is error_reporting

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having `include 'config.php'; // WHERE TO PUT THIS CANNOT FIND MYSQL` in each of your functions, add the $database parameter Eg `function mostPopular($database){...` and change `$mysqli->` to `$database->`

Then when you call the functions, pass the database through `mostPopular($database)`

On an unrelated note: You may also find it easier to have the functions return an array rather than echo HTML so that your functions just get the data format it and return values. (It also means you can get away from echoing full HTML.

Here is an example using your `mostPopular` function

Function:

```
function mostPopular($databaseName){
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ForumId, ForumTitle, ForumPostText FROM forum ORDER BY Views DESC  LIMIT  5");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($ForumId,$ForumTitle,$ForumPostText);
    $stmt->store_result();

    $returnData = array();

    if($stmt->num_rows() > 0){
        $i = 0;
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
            $returnData[$i]['ForumId'] = $ForumId;
            $returnData[$i]['ForumTitle'] = $ForumTitle;
            $returnData[$i]['ForumPostText'] = substr($ForumPostText, 0,93) . ' ...';
            ++$i;
        }
            $stmt->free_result();
        }
    }
    return $returnData;
}
```

Use:

```
<div id="mostPopular">
<?php
    $mostPopular = mostPopular($mysqli);

    if(count($mostPopular) === 0){ 
?>
    <p>No latest article available</p>
<?php 
    } else {
        foreach($mostPopular as $Popular){ 
?>
        <p class="posttitle"><a href="post.php?post=<?php echo $Popular['ForumId'];?>"><?php echo $Popular['ForumTitle'];?></a></p>
        <p class="posttext"><?php echo $Popular['ForumPostText'];?></p>
<?php 
        }
    }
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that the config.php script is not started with the PHP start tag of

```
<?php
```

The config file should be like this:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'userone', 'password', 'iitb');
```

EDIT: Make sure also to check the php_short_tags. It could be that the config.php file starts with a short tag `<?` and the short_open_tag is disabled on your localhost server.

Comment: He obviously just took that line out of the file. He described that it worked perfectly on his live server but not on the localhost server.

Comment: In that case, it could be the short tags. I have added to the answer.

Comment: The PHP tags are not the issue here though. I'm sure the file has the PHP tags since the script works perfectly fine on his live server but not on his local server. If tags would be the issue, the script wouldn't work on any PHP server.

Comment: There are two PHP start tags: `<?php` and `<?`(Short Tag). If the production server has short tags enabled, and the localhost has them disabled, `<?` short tag would work and be parsed as a PHP script correctly on the production server but on the localhost, the short tag would just be treated as plain text - thus the `$mysqli = new MYSQLi` won't be executed.